# Nothing happens after Capistrano deploy command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, rubygems, capistrano

I am using Capistrano gem for deploy management of my Ruby on Rails app. Its connected with AWS server, EC2, MySQL Redis. While I am putting my command "cap production deploy" or "cap staging deploy" nothing happens. I just got stuck there.

To add here my SSH key is properly added. And in my AWS security groups, only the authorized IPs are added to have the permission of deploying. My IPs are also added.

But when I add open ports 0.0.0.0/0 in all security groups it allows me to deploy. But I shouldn't add open ports for the sace of application security.

What can be the reason and how to solve these?

screenshot of my console, nothing happens

[image: X]

Below is my deploy.rb file:

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake] = 'bundle exec rake'
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.8.1'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url, 'git@gitlab.com:_____'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :rvm_roles, [:app, :web]
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.4.0'

set :log_level, :debug
set :pty, false
set :linked_files, %w{config/application.yml config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/assets public/uploads}

set :keep_releases, 10
set :whenever_roles, [:web, :app,:db]
set :whenever_identifier, "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}"

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'restart (upgrade) unicorn server'
  task :restart do
    invoke 'unicorn:restart'
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
  after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      within release_path do
        execute :rake, 'tmp:cache:clear'
      end
    end
  end

end

namespace :delayed_job do

  desc 'List of running delayed job workers'
  task :list do
    on roles(:all) do |host|
      execute :ps, 'aux | grep delayed_job'
    end
  end

  desc 'Stop delayed_job workers forcefully'
  task :kill do
    on roles(:all) do |host|
      execute :kill, "-9 $(ps aux | grep delayed_job | awk '{print $2}')"
    end
  end

end

task :upload_secret_files do
  on roles(:all) do |host|
    begin
      execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    rescue
    end
    upload! 'config/application.yml', "#{shared_path}/config/application.yml"
    upload! 'config/database.yml', "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end

task :log do
  on roles(:all) do |host|
    execute "tail -f #{current_path}/log/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.log"
  end
end

desc 'Invoke a rake command on the remote server'
task :invoke, [:command] => 'deploy:set_rails_env' do |task, args|
  on primary(:app) do
    within current_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        rake args[:command]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: check your capistrano log file (on your app's logs folder), maybe there's something on the file

Comment: Please post your deploy.rb code here.

Comment: @MohitKumar deploy.rb code is added above just below my post.

Comment: @arieljuod checked my log file. Nothing unusual there..

Comment: Did you get any timeout message ?

Comment: @MohitKumar no. After waiting for a very long time, I have to abort and exit the deploy. Should I wait for a long time like an hour or so and see what happens till the end :/

Comment: @ShakilMahmood Were you ever able to find a solution for this problem? I am getting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with exactly the same issue and spent several hours. Didn't get what is the issue related to. It just started working after I reboot my local OS